# как растянуть задний фон на всю ширину окна

Tags: css3, html5

свойство `height: 100vh` не помогает потому что при уменьшении экрана из за него ломается верстка и контент в следующем блоке сьезжает[image: верстка]

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: верхний блок это header за ним идет section, вот стили header: 
`header{
 position: relative;
 background-image: url("../loot/cover/field.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
 font-family: Gotham Pro;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100vh;
}`